# Existence of a continuous cutoff function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $B \subset A$ is closed. Then there exists  a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $f(x) \in [0, 1] \quad  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
2. $f(x) = 1 \quad \forall x \in B$
3. $f(x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$.

My reading material claims that the claim is trivial if $B$ or $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$ is empty, but doesn't further ellaborate why. So why is the claim trivial in that case?

Comment: If one of the two sets is empty you can let $f$  be a _constant_ function...

Comment: What are $F,G$ and how are they related to $A,B$?

Comment: @almosteverywhere I had mixed my notes, so $A = G, F = B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit of an overkill but Urysohn's lemma provides an answer to your question in the general case. Note that $A^c$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint and so they can be separated by a continuous function taking values in $[0,1]$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma.

For the simple scenario: in case $B$ is empty choose $f \equiv 0$ and in case $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ is empty choose $f \equiv 1$.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove this in a general metric space relatively easily using the fact that distance to a set is continuous. The intuition is that when $B$ is a closed interval and $A$ is an open interval, $f(x)$ will give the ratio of the distance from $x$ to $A^c$ to the total distance $d(x, B) + d(x, A^c)$. The formal execution is
$$f(x) = \frac{d(x, A^c)}{d(x, B) + d(x, A^c)}.$$
Note that if $F$ is closed, then $d(x, F) = 0 \iff x \in F$. Thus since $B \cap A^c = \emptyset$, the denominator of $f(x)$ is always positive, so $f(x)$ is well defined. $f$ has all the desired properties.

With quite a bit more work, you can prove the existence of smooth partitions of unity on an arbitrary smooth manifold, such as $\mathbb{R}^n$. The existence of smooth partitions of unity yields your result as a corollary, and shows that $f$ can be taken to be smooth ($C^{\infty}$).